# Special characters are shown different

Tags: html

I just finished a website. Special characters like ăîâșț show perfect on my PC, however on some devices those characters look bold, something like this:

[image: http://puu.sh/defG5/0481e93565.jpg]

This is the charset:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

On iPhone all the special characters are replaced with a square.

In some places in order to test thins I replaced the ă character with `&#259;` . Same problem.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Which font-face is used?

Comment: Yeah, it seems as if the font face you are using does not have those characters on the iPhone. I'm guessing it is a webfont. Try setting the font to 'sans-serif', if all characters load correctly you have encoding right and that will confirm the issue is with the font missing characters

Comment: Show enough HTML and CSS code reproduce the issue. A short fragment of text should suffice. The font settings are most important.

Comment: I changed the font from "Open Sans" (Google Web Fonts) to Arial (System Fonts) and it seems to be ok. Thanks for the help!